# Buddypress padding

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have a problem with padding on my website. I used inspect tool, found where I can change it. In inspect mode I can change padding. On backend WordPress plugin editor, css I can't change the same thing. How can I change this?  Pleasee see screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to modify the css file if the plugin don't allow you to modify it directly.
Otherwise you can add your css modification directly into the Apparence -> Customize -> Additional CSS.

Comment: Will need more info on which part you want to change exactly, but basically you can use one of this : padding-left, padding-right, padding-top or padding-bottom. And then applied a value in percentage or px for example.
an example for the class test will be :
.test{
   padding-top:5px;
}

Comment: Do you have any code for mobile version? On my laptop is great but on mobile I need to change this padding.

Comment: You can use Media query : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Thanks I only see width, what about height?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have fixed it on mobile.